# Display Name, Phone, Email from Android Contacts Content Provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

First I get the id of the contact that interest me based on the name and then I query again where for CONTACT_ID is the id I retrieved.

So my projection and my where clause are :

```
            String[] projection = new String[] {
                    ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
            };

            String where = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id 
                        + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = '" +
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'"
                        + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = '" +
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";
```

If I remove one of the two ***AND***  checks I'm having on the where clause and the corresponding field from the projection I' m having the correct result. But for **both** Email and Phone that can't happen. I'm getting twice the same result. That means for the code above I'll get 2 times the email address. If I move the Phone.NUMBER field before Email.ADDRESS I'll get 2 times the phone number.

The code for the query :

```
            Cursor dCursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, where,
                null, null);

        int nameIdx = dCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int emailIdx = dCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS);
        int phoneIdx = dCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
```